# Hiding and displaying a profile on click

Tags: javascript

I have got a list of drivers and when I click on one of them I am getting more information about them from the list. I am trying to write a function that will hide this information when I click again on the same driver.

Function that generates more information about the driver:

```
function driverProfile(drivers2020) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const article = document.createElement('article');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');

  h1.textContent = drivers2020[driver_id].name;
  span.textContent = drivers2020[driver_id].age;
  article.textContent = drivers2020[driver_id].nationality;
  div.appendChild(h1);
  div.appendChild(span);
  div.appendChild(article);
  return div;
  }

myProfile = driverProfile(drivers2020);
profile.appendChild(myProfile);
```

I tried that, but the click hides then shows again:

```
const listOfNames = document.getElementById("listOfNames");  //listOfNames is an id of <a> tag for every driver in the list
listOfNames.addEventListener('click', hideProfil);

function hideProfil() {
profile.style.display = "none";
 }
```

html:

```
  <div id="list2020">

  </div>
  <section id="profile">

  </section>
```

function that displays names and images of all drivers:

```
drivers2020.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, index) {
  const nameList = document.createElement('a');
  const driverImg = document.createElement('img');
  nameList.href = `?driver=${index}`;
  nameList.id = "listOfNames";
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  driverImg.src = driver.image;
  driverImg.height = "45";
  driverImg.style.cssText = 'margin: 0px 0px -15px 10px; '
  list2020.appendChild(nameList);
  nameList.appendChild(driverImg);
 }
```

an array list:

```
const drivers2020 = [{
  name: "Kimi Raikonnen",
  age: "20",
  nationality: "Finland",
  image: "drivers/kimi.jpg"
},
{
  name: "George Russel",
  age: "30",
  nationality: "UK",
  image: "drivers/russel.jpg"
}
]
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tmoafLp/4/)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @thodwris I am not really familiar with jsfiddle, I have tried to put something together, but it doesnt work

Comment: This worries me: `//listOfNames is an id of <a> tag for every driver in the list` as ids need to be unique. Can you please add all of the relevant code (html, where and how `driverProfile` is called...)?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have added the rest of the code to the post

Comment: add some example to `driver2020` variable which is not defined in ur code

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A drivers2020 is a list, a have added that as well

Comment: you want to hide them but they hsow up again? is it the problem?

Comment: yes when I click on the name of the driver, the information about him is popping out, I want to hide that information when I click again on his name

Comment: I'd wrapped all ur code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6q2uch8t/), but it isn't working the way you described; you can do the same and put the link into ur question so others can collaborate more easily

Comment: there's 2 line of code missing `const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const driver_id = urlParams.get('driver');` displaying the information of the drivers is based on the url, I dont think you can do that in fiddle it throws an error 404 page not found

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A ok here https://jsfiddle.net/9tmoafLp/4/ , i got it to work

Comment: There are so many wrong things with this approach. Writing a working example would mean rewriting more than half of your code, but I don't want to write all the code for you. If you need help, you can open up a chat with me and I'd be glad to point you in the right direction.

Comment: how do I open a chat?

Comment: I've opened up a [room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209230/room-for-el-vanja-and-menor).